# OKhttp provided examples are not complete

Tags: android, http, webclient, okhttp

I put this code into a new project:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/square/okhttp/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/guide/GetExample.java

I have added this to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I have added the gradle components to be pulled in otherwise it would not even compile but this code does absolutely nothing. The app crashes when I copy it in an empty app.

I have tried to put it into a "Basic Action" example, that does not crash at least but the code does not make http request.

```
package com.example.hellokitty;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String run(String url) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            return response.body().string();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MainActivity example = new MainActivity();
        String response = example.run("http://10.10.0.11/kek");
        System.out.println(response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This example is for raw Java. It won't run on android just because you pasted it into Activitys body, I recommend finding an android basics tutorial because it seems like you have no idea what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your code.
It crashes because you run network operation on main thread. And you get
[NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException) runtime exception.

To avoid this you need to replace

```
try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    return response.body().string();
}
```

with

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
        String url = response.body().string();
        //your code here
    }
});
```

The whole code will be:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private OkHttpClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        client = new OkHttpClient();
        
        run("http://10.10.0.11/kek");
    }

    private void run(String url) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response){
                String url = response.body().toString();
                //your code here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

So when you make a call to http://10.10.0.11/kek you will receive
*java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to * not permitted*

That's why you will need to enable clear text traffic in security config.

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Create file res/xml/network_security_config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
</network-security-config>
```